# "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" -unable to upload .gif from the web

Tags: bug

While I am trying to include an image into my question I am getting below mentioned error

```
Failed to upload image; the format is not supported
```

Could some one tell me, **what are the supported image file formats available
    in SO to upload?**

In "**Add Image**" pop up there is nothing mentioned about the supported formats and even in the error message this information is missing. How user will know what image file formats are allowed to upload in SO? **Is not it better to mention the supported image file formats in the error message?**

The image i am trying to upload is https://s3.amazonaws.com/nrjio/Stretchy-480.gif

Comment: I just tried one of Chris' suggestions to attempt to help you figure out your problem. The method I tried was to download the image. But instead of converting it (since I assume you want the animation) I just tried to upload it directly and received a much different error message, which may very well be your issue: _"Image uploads are limited to 2Mb. Please use a smaller image"_ The size of the gif, according to my machine, is 2.07Mb. If you are the creator of the image and you can make the file smaller, do so and try again.

Comment: @Kendra but while I am trying to upload the image  by selecting "From the web" radio button, it should also show the same error message what ever u r getting. If the size of the image is the main reason then both the cases it should show the same error message. but it showing two completely different error messages. Why?

Comment: I am not an SE developer, and cannot tell you why. I am only telling you what I found by trying this in a different manner. That is why I did not post an answer- It's a solution to your issue, but not an answer to your feature-request.

Comment: same happened like @Kendra

Comment: @Arin: I re-tagged your question from `feature-request` to `bug` as the error message was misleading. But yes, it seems the Help Center mentions images but does not list the supported *types*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Help on Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) mentions images but does not list the supported types. From experience only: JPEG, PNG, and also GIF images are *definitely* supported. [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) says

> The HTML standard doesn't give a list of image formats that must be
>   supported, so each user agent supports a different set of formats.
>   Gecko supports:
>
> JPEG
>   GIF, including animated GIFs
>   PNG
>   APNG
>   SVG
>   BMP
>   BMP ICO
>   PNG ICO

but of course the image loader itself makes the ultimate choice. ... And indeed, when trying an `SVG` I get the following message:

> **Failed to upload; not a valid image (jpeg, png, tiff, gif or bmp)**

I've used a GIF a couple of times [for animation purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21968854/2564301), but the image you are trying to upload is too large. When uploading "From my computer", I get a clear error message in bold red text:

[image: error message]

"Image uploads are limited to 2Mb. Please use a smaller image" – the file is 78,074 bytes larger than (a reasonable value for) 2Mb.

Strangely I get "Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" when trying to insert the image from the URL. This may need fixing.

Comment: Gee, wish I'd have thought to try this. :) (I don't have anything to make a gif with to help prove this, so you've got a better answer than I could've written by proving the format is indeed supported.)